# How to parse multi properties with spacing in jq json bash script?

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

I have a json string in the following format:

```
json='{"x": [{"y":"yyy1", "z":"zzz1 zzz1"}, {"y":"yyy2", "z":"zzz2 zzz2"}]}'
```

I'm trying to get an array var of all "y" and separate array of "z" with jq like

```
y_arr=$(echo "${json}" | jq '.x | [] | .y') # => outputs 2 array elements 
y_arr=$(echo "${json}" | jq '.x | [] | .z') # => outputs 4 array elements due to space
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?
Also, do you know any better way of parsing the json as single key/value array instead of two separate arrays?

Comment: "...instead of two separate arrays"????  Please explain what you mean, e.g. with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your bash has `readarray` (aka `mapfile`) and that having the bash array values be valid JSON is acceptable, you could write:

```
readarray z_array < <(echo "${json}" | jq -c '.x[] | .z')
```

With your $json, this would yield an array of JSON strings (with quotation marks).

### shell loop

If your shell does not support `readarray`,
then you could use the same invocation of jq but read the values in a bash loop, e.g.:

```
declare -a array
while read v
do
    array+=("$v")
done < <(echo "${json}" | jq -c '.x[] | .z')
```

#### Strings

If all the .z values are JSON strings, then provided these strings do not have embedded newline characters, and that you want the bash array values to be "raw" strings (as opposed to JSON strings), you could add the -r option to the invocation of jq.

### Associative Arrays

If your bash supports associative arrays, consider:

```
declare -A a
i=0
while read v
do
    i=$((i+1))
    a["$v"]=$i
done < <(echo "${json}" | jq -c '.x[].z') 

declare -p a

for i in "${!a[@]}" ; do
  echo $i
done
```

This produces:

```
declare -A a=(["\"zzz2 zzz2\""]="2" ["\"zzz1 zzz1\""]="1" )
"zzz2 zzz2"
"zzz1 zzz1"
```

Comment: this returns result like y_arr=([0]="yyy1" [1]="yyy2")  while i'm looking to get result like this y_arr=["yyy1", "yyy2"] so  that i can for loop over it as string array

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in associative arrays. If so, please see the update.